Passing variable in Github actions
I have a reusable workflow which has multiple jobs. I have a job let's say job1 which is a multi step job, one of the step calls a action which resides in some other directory, i want to set a vairable in that action as output then use it in other step of job1. How can i achieve this.

There are 2 types of variables that can be set by an action:

Output Variables
Environment variables

Output Variables
The Output variables are the more secure option, since they can't be influenced by steps between the action setting the variable and the action accessing the variable.
To set an output variable you must do 2 things:

Add an id to the step setting the variable
Append the name=value string to the file that captures variables

This generally looks like this:
- name: Set color
  id: color-selector
  run: |
     "SELECTED_COLOR=green" >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT
  shell: pwsh

You can then access using the following syntax: ${{ steps.color-selector.outputs.SELECTED_COLOR }} and, for example, assign it to an input of environment variable of a step called further on in your workflow:
- name: Get color
  env:
     SELECTED_COLOR: ${{ steps.color-selector.outputs.SELECTED_COLOR }}
  run: Write-Output "The selected color is $env:SELECTED_COLOR"
  shell: pwsh

Or:
- name: Get color
  uses: someowner/someaction
  with:
    color: ${{ steps.color-selector.outputs.SELECTED_COLOR }}

Other actions in the same job can only access this output variable when it is explicitly passed to them as seen above.
An output variable can also be used to set the output variable of a whole job, in case you want to reference the value in another job that is dependent on, needs:, the job in which the variable was set:
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Map a step output to a job output
    outputs:
      output1: ${{ steps.step1.outputs.test }}
      output2: ${{ steps.step2.outputs.test }}
    steps:
      - id: step1
        run: echo "test=hello" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
        shell: bash
      - id: step2
        run: echo "test=world" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
        shell: bash
  job2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: job1
    steps:
      - env:
          OUTPUT1: ${{needs.job1.outputs.output1}}
          OUTPUT2: ${{needs.job1.outputs.output2}}
        run: echo "$OUTPUT1 $OUTPUT2"
        shell: bash

Environment variables
An environment variable is set in a very similar way, but will be available through the environment to any step in the same job following the current step:
steps:
  - name: Set the value
    id: step_one
    run: |
      echo "action_state=yellow" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
    shell: bash
  - name: Use the value
    id: step_two
    run: |
      printf '%s\n' "$action_state" # This will output 'yellow'
    shell: bash

A note on syntax
The exact syntax to set an output or environment variable depends on the Shell or programming language being used. The official GitHub docs contains examples for both:

bash
powershell / pwsh

But the concept translates to other languages as well. I've blogged on how to issue workflow commands from the classic Windows Shell. But the concept is similar whether you use Python, or MsBuild or any other programming language. Variables are set by appending a string in UTF-8 to the file referenced by the respective environment variable.
